# Working with nodeJS sessions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building login and logout functionality when I click on login it generate my session but when i click on logout it does not destroy my session how to solve it ?  *** I have checked evey where for the solution.***
And I am using mongodb for checking credentials.This is my code.

```
app.post('/checkadminlogin', (req,res) => {
    // console.log(req.body);
    var email = req.body.email;

    var password = req.body.password;
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err,db) => {

        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection('adminlogin').find({ 'email': email, 'password': password }, {_id: 1, email: 1, password: 1}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err;

            if(Object.keys(result).length === 0){
            res.send("Email or Password is wrong");         
            }           
            else{
                adminsess = JSON.stringify(result[0].email);
                req.session.admin = adminsess;
                res.redirect('/admindashboard');    
            }
        });
    }); 
});


app.get('/logoutadmin', (req,res) => {      
            req.session.reset();
            res.redirect('/');  
});
```

Comment: How do you check session is created or not ?

Comment: console.log(req.session.admin);

Comment: so what it returns?

Comment: Try `req.session.destroy()`.

Comment: @MiguelCalderón  I checked not working

Comment: @pardeep it returns admin@admin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use this code ( Written below )  for your logout route.

```
  app.get('/logoutadmin', (req,res) => {        
    req.session.destroy(function () {               
     res.redirect('/');              
    });     
  });
```